# Converting Column of Dataframe to Seq[Columns] Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, aggregation

I am trying to make the next operation:

```
var test = df.groupBy(keys.map(col(_)): _*).agg(sequence.head, sequence.tail: _*)
```

I know that the required parameter inside the agg should be a `Seq[Columns]`.

I have then a dataframe "expr" containing the next:

```
sequences
count(col("colname1"),"*")
count(col("colname2"),"*")
count(col("colname3"),"*")
count(col("colname4"),"*")
```

The column sequence is of string type and I want to use the values of each row as input of the `agg`, but I am not capable to reach those.

Any idea of how to give it a try?

Comment: It would be possible to convert to columns if the `expr` dataframe contained SQL commands. Otherwise it would probably be easier to find the column names and apply `col` and `count` afterwards.

Comment: the expression is written in scala format sum(when(col("Column").like("Value"), col("Column")) is an example, so I think the expr way does not fits here. I do not well understand the second approach you tell. Could you provide a simple example? or an extended explanation, thanks

Comment: The second approach would only be viable if the expressions were the same but on different columns (as in the question). From your comment it looks like the expressions are different though.

Comment: and about "It would be possible to convert to columns if the expr dataframe contained SQL commands" what exactly you referring?,e.g. I could have sum(CASE WHEN "column" LIKE "value" THEN "Column" END) AS `alias` an SQL expression

Comment: Yes, it's possible. I added an answer to explain it a bit more in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can change the strings in the `sequences` column to be SQL commands, then it would be possible to solve. Spark provides a function [`expr`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#expr-java.lang.String-) that takes a SQL string and converts it into a column. Example dataframe with working commands:

```
val df2 = Seq("sum(case when A like 2 then A end) as A", "count(B) as B").toDF("sequences")
```

To convert the dataframe to `Seq[Column]`s do:

```
val seqs = df2.as[String].collect().map(expr(_))
```

Then the `groupBy` and `agg`:

```
df.groupBy(...).agg(seqs.head, seqs.tail:_*)
```